# Converting cURL cmd to javascript

Tags: jquery, curl

I have the following cURL cmd. How can I achieve the same with javascript?

```
curl -X POST   https://api.cloudsight.ai/v1/images   -H 'authorization: CloudSight My_Key'   -H 'cache-control: no-cache'   -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW'   -F locale=en_US  -F image=@/home/Address_to_image/hello.jpg
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var request = require('request');

var headers = {
    'authorization': 'CloudSight My_Key',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW'
};

var options = {
    url: 'https://api.cloudsight.ai/v1/images',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body);
    }
}

request(options, callback);
```